# Displaying interstitial admob when the game is over with Sprite Kit and iOS

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to display adds when the game is over for my game app. I have created a game over variable on GameScene.swift and I call that variable in the GameViewController.swift. However, the add is displayed shortly after the game starts. Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds

private var interstitial: GADInterstitial?

class GameViewController: UIViewController,  GADInterstitialDelegate {

    private var interstitial: GADInterstitial?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interstitial = createInterstitial()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.



            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    private func createInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5713504307801022/7610056592")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()

        request.testDevices = ["ca-app-pub-5713504307801022/7610056592"]
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        return interstitial
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        interstitial = createInterstitial()
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

        if (interstitial!.isReady)  {
            if gameOver1 == true {
            self.interstitial!.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstitial = createInterstitial()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the gameOver1 Bool value is correct? Could you print that value in the log to check it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have assigned the value true, and when i print it it shows up as true.

Answer (score 0):

First - this is how you should load and recycle AdMob interstitials -https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938286/2405378

Second - viewWillLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times and each time this method creates new instance of the GameScene - with gameOver1 being false?

Comment: How did you get the GameViewController+GADInterstitialDelegate.swift and AdMobHelper.swift? Did you have to import some framework?

Comment: No - this is "my" code. Just add this two files to your project.